# Proving entire function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Let $f(z),z^5\bar{f}(z)$ be entire functions on $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I tried using Cauchy-Riemann quations in their polar form in order to find out the derivaties are zero and I got that $$\begin{cases}u_r=\frac 1 r v_\theta\\v_r=-\frac 1 r u_\theta\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Re(r^5 cis(\theta)f(r,\theta))=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Im(r^5 cis(\theta)f(r,\theta))\\\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Im(r^5 cis(\theta)f(r,\theta))=-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Re(r^5 cis(\theta)f(r,\theta))\end{cases}$$ which is a complex system of PDEs. I also thought using Liouville's theorem but I don't know how to prove that $f$ is a bounded function. Can I get any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(z)$ is entire, so is $z^5\, f(z)$. Hence $g(z)=z^5(f(z)+\overline f(z))$ is entire and $g(z)/z^5$ is a holomorphic real valued function in $\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: thanks, but $g(z)$ is not bounded and not entire on ${0}$.

Comment: @Danis: I imagine that if you show $f$ is constant on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, you can handle extending the result to the whole plane.

Comment: Not sure I understood but $g(z)$ doesn't have to be bounded (e.g if $f(z)=\sin(z)$).

Comment: $\overline{\sin(z)}$ is not entire. We are just using the hypothesis to show $f(z)+\overline f(z)$ is entire on $\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry for being nagger but why $f+\bar{f}$ is bounded?

Comment: $f+\overline f$ is bounded because is constant. If $f=u+iv$, then $f+\overline f=2u\in \Bbb R$, but a holomorphic real valued function must be constant.

Comment: Why it must be constant? For example what about $\exp(z)$?

Comment: You can check it is constant using the CR equations. The exponential function is not real valued, it is not true that $\exp(z)\in \Bbb R$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$.